# How to suspend/kill ptpcamerad?

Tags: launchd, ventura

The ptpcamerad process is preventing a python script from accessing a connected DSLR by not allowing use of the usb ports. I would like to know how to suspend or kill the process without it immediately respawning. I have tried:

1. Quit/Force Quit in Activity monitor (immediately respawns; cannot quit the owning process, as it is owned by launchd)
2. sudo kill [PID] (immediately appears with new PID; also respawns with -9)
3. launchctl disable gui/$(id -u)/com.apple.ptpcamerad (does nothing)

How can I stop this process from constantly respawning and preventing access to usb-connected cameras?

MacOs 13.3.1 (a) MacBookAir M1

Comment: This is likely a development question, but from reading your question, it sounds like you’re trying to access the USB port directly which is something you can’t do.  You should be using IOKit.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I am writing a python script that calls gphoto2 to take images in sequence (for an RTI dome) and download and save the images to batch folders. I can force it to run via sudo, but the accepted answer for Mac users of this script for about a decade until Ventura seems to have been killing the ptpcamera process which doesn't do anything necessary and would free up the camera for use by the python library. I accept that for a real application, IOKit might be the answer, but I have no C+++ knowledge

Comment: For Python look at PyObjC - the issue is that pure python just does not call the correct APIs so you need to call a C library that does.

Comment: I think that this has been helpful in establishing that I need to re-imagine how the cameras are controlled in this setup, and that drivers are going to stand in the way of it being meaningfully cross-platform in its current state. It probably makes more sense for me to have an integrated Raspberry Pi Zero controlling the hardware and camera, so we only need to worry about the (solved) drivers of one device, and then we have a multitude of ways to transfer the actual data to user computers.